# RoR: Inspecting an Uploaded File

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to inspect the bits of an uploaded file before it's ever saved off to the file system. PHP's documentation has a nice page that tells me exactly what properties are available for me to use (https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), but I can't find something similar for Ruby and/or Rails.

I've also tried logging a JSON-formatted string of the upload, but that just gives me a redundant UTF-8 error. I can't think of anything else to try.

Can anyone offer any insight or point me to the right place?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I'm running Apache 2.2.11 on OS X (Leopard) in case Peter is right (see below).

**UPDATE:** In case it helps, my input parameter is logged as `"upload"=>#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart.64239.1>`. I'm just not sure how to access it to get to its "parts".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I've been able to tell or find, there is no physical file until an upload is read. This is inline with derfred's reply. The only metadata that *can* be accessed is:

```
uploaded_file.content_type  # the uploaded file's MIME type
uploaded_file.original_path # which is really just the name of the file
```

Additionally, there's a `read` method on the `uploaded_file` that allows the file' content to be accessed and, presumably, written to the permanent file system.

Something else that I've noticed is that the *only* means Ruby offers to inspect the MIME type of a file is in this `content_type` property of an uploaded file. Once the file is on the file system, there's no longer any way of accessing or determining the MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on the web server you're using. I remember having different fields for mongrel, apache and nginx.

Comment: Ugh. I'll update the original question accordingly. I'm surprised at how little info I can find for this or about any way to reliably dump the upload.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Rails and the various app servers totally abstract the upload part. However here is a thorough discussion of the topic:
http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/04/10/rails-and-large-large-file-uploads-looking-at-the-alternatives/

Answer (score 0):

This is just a File object, something that you can duplicate by going:

```
File.open("some_file")
```

The */tmp/RackMultipart.64239.1* is just a filename.

If you want to see/output its contents from the controller:

```
 puts params[:upload].read
```

Comment: I guess I assumed that the filename represented a physical file that I could inspect before ever saving it to a permanent location. That doesn't appear to be the case. There are properties like content_type and original_filename that can be gleaned from the upload, but I can't find a complete set of which properties are available at that time.